# Can not update the import connection to AD

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, active-directory-import

I am using active directory import connection and I am not able to update the selected containers for the synchronization connection.  I just opened the edit connection page, enter the synchronization account password and click Populate Containers, scroll down and unselect a currently selected container and click OK.  The system showing the change is saved but if I go back the page that display the users and refresh it, unselected users still there. 
I tried to create a new connection to the Active directory and select the containers I want, then start the full crawl search. Even after 24 hours, I still have the old users!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make a change to connection, you have to run the full crawl followed by a couple of incremental crawls.

Full crawl is many time is not enough and you have to run the incremental sync after that.

Comment: I will try that again, but how many time it takes to be changed please? Is the result comes immediately ?

Comment: yes it shows once the import job completed? did you apply any filter in ldap syntax?

Comment: Nope, I didn't apply any filter. Thanks for your quick answer !

Comment: when you said create a new connection, did you delete the old one? how many users you are expecting?

Comment: Yes I deleted the old one and created a new one! I am importing hundreds of users. Thanks